# What is long-living business processes in ESB architecture?

Tags: process, esb, long-integer

I am reading about EIP and ESB, i saw article about lightweight ESB vs stand alone ESB.

"The main lack with lightweight ESBs is the impossibility to implement complex, long-living, business processes. That makes them inappropriate for an Enterprise top-down BPM approach. This limitation apart these light solutions cover all recurring integration requirements, in a more simple way. This is possible because they are built around integration best practices and conventions."

So what is "long-living business processes"? Can you give me examples?

Answer (score 0):

When a business process spans hours, Days, or weeks (etc.) from start to finish it is considered as a Long living process. So the process will have a certain state which span across time.When the ESB is light weight it is needed to drop some of the functionality such as message persistance and certain service orchestration features (Not as complex as Business process Engine but up to a reputed level.)